# JAXB xjc episodic compilation failing *in random way* (compiler was unable to honor ...)

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

**UPDATE 1:** I created a narrow-down of this problem with three minimal XSD files and posted a new question focusing on the problem itself (and not the randomness in the behavior  of **xjc**) [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274109/jaxb-compiler-was-unable-to-honor-this-schemabinding-customization).

**UPDATE 2:** Posted an issue report on JAXB's bug-tracker [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-965).

I am using the latest 2.2.7 **JAXB RI** implementation of **xjc** in a setup with a number of **xsd** schema files using episodic compilation. I am using **Ant** for the build, so that everything is reproducible, right? Wrong! It turns out that **xjc** code-generation fails with a message like the following:

```
  [xjc] [ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this schemaBinding customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
  [xjc]   line 581 of file:/home/boohaha/unableToHonorSchemaBinding/CEABase.xsd.episode
  [xjc] 
  [xjc] [ERROR] (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
  [xjc]   line 9 of file:/home/boohaha/unableToHonorSchemaBinding/src/_int/esa/esavo/ivoa/jaxb/schemas/VOResource-v1.0.xsd
  [xjc]
```

What's really appalling is that successive Ant invocations of the **xjc** task (`ant clean && ant`) **yield different results**. The compilation fails again, fails at the same target ( *jaxb-vo.ceaservice* ), the type of the message is the same (*unable to honor*) but **the particulars of the message are different** (it's complaining about some other line in some other file). I experimented a bit, and found out that there are 4 or 5 different locations it complains about (over multiple runs). In all cases it is the last binding in the file which to me suggests a bug in the **xjc** parsing code.

But, no matter what the bug or the mistake in my setup might be, it is inconceivable that a code generator should exhibit this random behavior! I became paranoid and tested everything many times, with no Internet connection. Same thing, the randomness persisted (interestingly, some lines appear much more frequently that others, but it's always the last binding). You can get the use case and try it yourselves with:

```
git clone https://github.com/mperdikeas/unable_to_honor.git && cd unable_to_honor && ant
```

My questions are:

1. Why do I get this error
2. How is it possible that the `xjc` code generator fails in a random way unless it uses some "clever" threading to speed things up

**UPDATE**
See update notes at the top of the post.

Comment: I found xjc to be non deterministic with regard to namespaces in the generated code apparently due to the use of non-sorted sets in the compiler. A bit of background is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552357/xjc-compile-result-is-random-leading-to-different-marshalled-xmls

Comment: It's an abomination that a code generator should fluctuate its output. If such is the state of the reference implementation, to me that calls the whole technology into question.